# From list of lists to a data frame keeping the number of the list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr

I have a list of lists similar to **df**.

```
x <- list("a" = 3:5, "b" = 2:4,"c" = 1:3)
y <- list("a" = 1:3, "b" = 2:4,"c" = 3:5)
df <- list(x, y)
```

I convert the list of lists (df) into a data frame (**data**) following the next command:

```
data <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, df)
```

However, in **data** I want to **keep** the **number of the list** as a **new variable** (in this case, value **1 for the first 3 lines** of data and **2 for the last 3 lines** of data???

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `bind_rows` with `.id` - by default if the `list` is unnamed, the column created ('grp') will return will the sequence of the `list`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df, .id = 'grp')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  grp       a     b     c
  <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1 1         3     2     1
2 1         4     3     2
3 1         5     4     3
4 2         1     2     3
5 2         2     3     4
6 2         3     4     5
```

Comment: Hi @akrun , how would you use the proposed code in the following context ``` lapply(df, function(x) do.call(rbind, x))```?

Comment: @vog If it is a list, you may use `purrr::map(lst1, ~ bind_rows(.x, .id = "grp"))`